# Line break is not working when editing at the end of previous line in fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

Line break is working fine when I am writing in current line but If I am trying to edit in previous line then line break is not working. I know the reason is line length is using as a array index of line width. so when I am going back to edit the array index remain same and the array width also remain same so it can't enter into the condition.please give some solution to over come this problem.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ayan27/pofpnuq3/12/)

```
var tempwidth=270;
canvas.on('text:changed', function(e) {
    console.log("Line Length",e.target._textLines.length);
        console.log("TargetText",e.target);
    objTEmp=e.target;
    var tLine = e.target._textLines.length;
    var lineWidthText = e.target.__lineWidths[tLine-1];
    console.log("TargetText",e.target.__lineWidths[tLine-1]);
    if (lineWidthText > tempwidth) {
       objTEmp.setText(e.target.text+' ');
       objTEmp.setText(objTEmp.getText());
       objTEmp.selectAll(); 
       objTEmp.setSelectionStart(objTEmp.text.length);
       objTEmp.setSelectionEnd(objTEmp.text.length);
       tempwidth=270;
       canvas.renderAll();
       console.log("TargetTextWidth",e.target.width);
       console.log("Changed Text Width",tempwidth);

      }
      });
```